How much propellent is vaporized to pressurize the Starship and Super Heavy tanks?
We know they use autogenous pressurization. But how much methane and oxygen is vaporised to do this? I would like a figure for each of the 8 individual tanks in the stack.
TBH I'm trying to figure out how big the explosion will be if (when?) the booster misses the OLM chopsticks on IFT-5.

The explosion will be the amount of propellant left, not just how much is vaporised. Liquid propellant will be rapidly vaporised during any RUD fire

Maximum operational pressure of the tanks is 6 bar. Volume and temperature are widely available. PV=nRT will give maximum mass of vapor.

@Woody temperature is widely available? News to me

@AbdullahisnotanAmalekite ... propellants are present in both liquid and gas phase at 6 bar. Temperature can be obtained from a phase diagram.

@Woody no it can't. Even at constant pressure you can vary mass of propellent by varying the temperature.

Not an answer: Graphic for comment to abdullah-is-not-an-amalekite
The maximum temperature in a Starship oxygen tank which contains both liquid and vapor in equilibrium can be obtained from an oxygen phase diagram.
This information can be used to calculate the maximum propellant vapor available for an accidental explosion, as requested in the OP

